# How to prevent starting activities through ADB Shell

Tags: android

It is obvious that setting exported to false and setting custom permissions is not working.
Any other suggestion ??

Comment: is your debug flag false in the manifest?

Comment: yep, it is false.

Comment: can you also share the manifest with how the activity is defined

Comment: As i told; exported is false and custom permission is set.
Other which activity xml attribute(s) you think may related to this issue ?

Comment: it can be, for other than the main activity the adb should be able to be blocked

Comment: @cmnl - How did you prevent starting activities from ADB

Comment: Hi @cmnl, Did you found any way to prevent starting activities through ADB Shell?